Process on SIGTERM callback is not triggered?
This is my code:
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('Got SIGTERM signal.')
})

process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')

Node: v20.16.0
OS: Windows 10
I executed the file by running node test.js. I expected to see Got SIGTERM signal logged to my console. However, there is nothing logged to my console. Can someone explain what I'm misunderstanding?

Why are you using signals to kill your own process?

@Bergi I'm not really doing it. I am trying to learn node.js a bit better and was  experimenting with processes. In this case, the result of running the code didn't make sense to me, therefore, decided to ask the question.

I see, but the first thing I'd have checked is whether it still happens when sending the signal from a different process (e.g. the task manager).

@Bergi Thanks for the idea. I set a long timeout to have the process running, after that  killed it via the task manager, and no logs. I guess I need to  test it in Linux environment. SIGINT is triggered though when I press CTRL-C.

Yes, process signals is something where you need a good understanding of the OS, and where there's significant differences between Windows and Linux

It is the OS issue. Windows is not using the signals same way you expect for Unix system.
Instead you can do the following
process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
});

process.exit(342);

It results: About to exit with code: 342
More info

Thank you. It's strange that if  I have  this code process.on('SIGINT', () => { console.log('Got SIGINT signal.') }) and press CTRL-C  I would get console.log. Is it something to do with process.kill method? Could you provide more info pls? I looked at the provided documentation, and I don't get it.

For your original issue when using SIGTERM, per the node.js docs this is not implemented on windows (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events).
Referencing the same node.js documents it outlines that SIGINT will be triggered by  CTRL-C across all platforms, which is why your above example is printing to the console.

@Mike thanks, I didn't see that in docs. It makes a lot of sense now!
